# Java unchecked cast to type parameter warning despite being instance of

Tags: java, type-parameter, unchecked-cast

Consider you have this List:

```
private final List<? extends AbstractXmlElement> inMemoryElements;
```

that contains a bunch of objects of subclasses of AbstractXmlElement and you want to add a method to filter objects of a specific subclass from that list. For this I created the following method:

```
public <E extends AbstractXmlElement> List<E> getInstancesOf(Class<E> c) {
    return getUsableElements().stream()
        .filter(c::isInstance)
        .map(e -> (E) e)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Yet (E) e results in an UncheckedCast Warning. I was wondering how exactly this is an unchecked cast and if it is safe to suppress this warning since those objects that are not an instance of E are filtered out before the cast. Meaning that, as far as I know, the cast should never fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an unchecked cast because the type of `E` is [unknown at runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Since you're checking `isInstance()`, your code is safe. But if you want to avoid the warning, you can use `c` to do the cast:

```
.map(c::cast)
```

Answer (score 2):

> how exactly this is an unchecked cast

Your only guarantee is that `e` is an instance of `AbstractXmlElement`. But it could be any subclass. So if you had a subclass `A` and `B` both extending `AbstractXmlElement`, theoretically the type constraint means you could attempt to cast `A` to `B`, which would fail, if you passed `B.class` as the argument and your collection contained instances of `A`. Hence the warning.

Note that the compiler doesn't go and check your filter expression to figure out that only instances of `E` can ever make it past the filter; in particular it does not go and read documentation and then also assume that documentation is correct. As far as it can tell, `c::isInstance()` is just another random method taking an `Object` and returning a `boolean`. There is at that point nothing to indicate only instances of `E` remain in the stream past the filter.

> if it is safe to suppress this warning

In this case, yes.

Comment: The risk of casting to an incorrect type is always present. It's not the reason for the unchecked cast warning.